# css: how to display two products in one row using each loop (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css

Need some help in css.

i have an array of products and m displaying it using each loop. I wanna show two products in each row. do you know how to do it? currently i am using 50% width of div so two products will come in div.

Is there any other way?

Here is code:

```
<div id="product_list" >
    <% if @products.size <= 0 %>
        <h1/>No products found</h1>
            <% else %>
                <% @products.each do |p| %>
                    <div class="products">

                        <div><%= image_tag p.photos.first.avatar.url(:big) if p.photos.size > 0 %>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

div product_list is main div
div products is 50%.
So it displays 2 div under main.

But this behaves weird when filters based on category etc. Is there any good way for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- 

I many times handle such situation like this, try if it works for you.

pseudo code:

```
<div id="product_list" >
<% if @products.size <= 0 %>
    <h1/>No products found</h1>
        <% else %>
           <ul><li class="products">
            <% @products.each do |p| %>

                    <%= (count%2==0):'</li><li>':''; %>

                    <div><%= image_tag p.photos.first.avatar.url(:big) if p.photos.size > 0 %>

                </div>
            <% end %>
           </li></ul>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: hey got the solution: <% @products.in_groups_of(2).each do |product_array| %><% product_array.each do |p| %>